# How could we separate grape api resources into multiple files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest, grape-api

Hi I am developing a simple api in ruby using intridea's grape. Let's say we have this:

```
class API_v1 < Grape::API
  resource :foo do
  end

  resource :bar do
  end

end
```

How could I make it so that the declaration for `:foo` and `:bar` are in separate files? Basically, I wanted to know if it is possible to have something similar to rails controllers where there are multiple files to organize the code.

I hope someone can give me an insight on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ruby has [open classes](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_open_classes.html), so you should be able to simply move those to separate files.

```
# foo.rb
class API_v1 < Grape::API
  resource :foo do
  end
end

# bar.rb
class API_v1 < Grape::API
  resource :bar do
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8):

The README recommends you use `mount`:

```
class Foo < Grape::API
  resource :foo ... 
end

class Bar < Grape::API
  resource :bar ... 
end

class API < Grape::API
  mount Foo
  mount Bar
end
```